# Python __float__() magic method not converting my custom class object

Tags: python

I am trying to use 2 classes to calculate the perimeter of a triangle. Whatever I do I cannot convert the 3 triangle legs' lengths from data type "Point" (vertice1, vertice2, vertice3) into  floats. The following error is displayed when I sum them to get the perimeter of the triangle :

```
  File "main.py", line 37, in perimeter
    self.__total += float(self.__mylist[element])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'
```

Here is the code :

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.__x = float(x)
        self.__y = float(y)

    def getx(self, x2):
        return x2 - self.__x

    def gety(self, y2):
        return y2 - self.__y

    def distance_from_xy(self, x2, y2):
        return math.hypot(self.getx(x2), self.gety(y2))

    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        return math.hypot(self.getx(point.__dict__['_Point__x']), 
        self.gety(point.__dict__['_Point__y']))

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, vertice1, vertice2, vertice3):
        self.__vertice1 = vertice1
        self.__vertice2 = vertice2
        self.__vertice3 = vertice3
        self.__mylist = [self.__vertice1, self.__vertice2, self.__vertice3]
        self.__total = 0
       
    def __float__(self):
        return self.__mylist[self.__vertice1], self.__mylist[self.__vertice2], 
        self.__mylist[self.__vertice3]

    def perimeter(self):
        for element in range(0, len(self.__mylist)):
            self.__total += float(self.__mylist[element])
        return self.__total

triangle = Triangle(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(0, 1))
print(triangle.perimeter())
```

Following my research, I understand that I need to convert my custom class object into a float before to be able to use the "+" operator but I am obviously wrong somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: From your code, you are trying to convert a `Point` object to a `float`.

Comment: Perimeter of triangle ABC = AB+BC+CA, why do you do `float(self.__mylist[element])`? What are you trying to achieve here?

You have distance_from_xy and distance_from_point methods, why you are not using them?

Comment: `__float__` is supposed to return a single `float` value. The intent is to define what `float(Triangle(x, y, z))` means, and in fact `float` will raise a `TypeError` if `Triangle.__float__` doesn't return a `float` when it gets called.

Comment: @BenY Yes, that is what I want to do and also why I have posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that I need to convert my custom class object into a float before to be able to use the "+" operator but I am obviously wrong somewhere.

At the part where you're never telling Python *how* to convert your custom type to a float: `float` will work out of the box on "built-in" types, but for a custom type (such as the `Point` you're using it on) it just calls [the `__float__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__float__). Since there is no `Point.__float__`, it raises an error instead, your `Point` is not convertible to a float.

Your code also makes no sense, as you're apparently trying to convert the individual points to floats, and... that doesn't really make sense? I guess you could express a point as the decimal value `x.y` but then the addition of these makes no sense.

Why don't you just compute the distances between your three points and add that? You even have helper functions for that...

Other issues.

- your use of `__` is incorrect, the purpose of the double-underscore prefix is not to emulate private variables in other languages (that is *not a thing* in Python), [it's to avoid innocent conflicts during inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)
- why are you accessing `__dict__` and mangled attribute names?
- why are you storing both individual vertices and a list of all vertices?
- `getx` and `gety` are very strange names for what are apparently the x and y distances between points
- why are you storing the perimeter on the Triangle, and not even using that as a cache?

Suggestion: something along the lines of

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def distance(self, other):
        return abs(math.hypot(other.x - self.x, other.y - self.y))

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, vertice1, vertice2, vertice3):
        self.v1 = vertice1
        self.v2 = vertice2
        self.v3 = vertice3

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.v1.distance(self.v2)\
             + self.v2.distance(self.v3)\
             + self.v3.distance(self.v1)

triangle = Triangle(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(0, 1))
print(triangle.perimeter())
```

or slightly more modern:

```py
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

    def distance(self, other):
        return math.dist(astuple(self), astuple(other))

@dataclass
class Triangle:
    v1: Point
    v2: Point
    v3: Point

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.v1.distance(self.v2)\
             + self.v2.distance(self.v3)\
             + self.v3.distance(self.v1)

triangle = Triangle(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(0, 1))
print(triangle.perimeter())
```

For perimeter we could go wild with weird functional code and it'd definitely be fun, but it'd also be less readable *and* less efficient:

```py
    def perimeter(self):
        return sum(map(
            Point.distance,
            attrgetter('v1', 'v2', 'v3')(self),
            attrgetter('v2', 'v3', 'v1')(self),
        ))
```

alternatively leaning more on the dataclass features:

```py
    def perimeter(self):
        points = astuple(self)
        points2 = points[1:] + points[:1]
        return sum(map(math.dist, points, points2))
```

(at which point `Point.distance` is a bit obsolete)